# how to horizontally align 4 imageview with textview

Tags: android

I want to show four `ImageView`s horizontally together with `TextView`s. This is [my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9QDP.png) and sample screen which I want to make. How can I do that?

[image]

> XML code:

```
 <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#CCCCCC"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It would probably be better if you did a rough sketch of what you want...

Comment: see this image  http://imgur.com/N3fKwmm i wan tto make right side image panel

Comment: 4 imageview with textview

Comment: Then say you want an ImageView WITH a textview underneath each, I didn't notice the text because it was so small. But follow @J2K solution will work if you apply that N times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works. I checked.

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hai there" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hai there" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hai there " />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hai there" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap each ImageView/TextView pair in a LinearLayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/group1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal>
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@strings/my_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: Added gravity attribute to keep everything in line

Comment: +1. Don't forget to add a gravitylayout centerhorizontal on both childs.

Comment: The picture you supplied made it look like you wanted the images to have text under them like a caption. That's what my answer tries to accomplish. Is that what you're looking for is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

Use TableRow and place all the images in that. Don't forget to give android:layout weight=1.

```
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: what about testview? how to add textview below each image?

Comment: give android:layout weight=1 to imageview or tablelayout?

Comment: weight should be given to imageview

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0f" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_weight=".25f"
    />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:layout_weight=".25f"
    />
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:layout_weight=".25f"
    />
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
     android:layout_weight=".25f"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what about testview? how to add textview below each image?

Comment: @user2947238 you can also give weight to testView...and where are your testview

Comment: i dontknow how to align textview below eah imageview please help ad textview also for below each imageview